# send $_POST data via anchor tag

Tags: php, html, post, anchor

is it possible to somehow send `$_POST[]` data via a `<a>` tag? because it seems to automaticly execute the `$_POST[]` once the page loads rather than when I press the Anchor tag.

**edit:**
so what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

I want an anchor tag which would normaly go to `somepage.php?variable=something`
but instead of using `$_GET[]` I want to send the variable via `$_POST`

Comment: Please make your requirement more clear

Comment: What isn't clear on it? I want to send `$_POST[]` values using anchor tags, basicly as you would use `someurl.php?action=derp` but rather than using `$_GET[]` I want to use `$_POST[]`

Comment: Answer is no. What you can do is set the value of an input type when the <a> tag gets clicked. Using Javascript.

Comment: Perhaps with a javascript listener to then fire an AJAX request onclick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery and a HTML form

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="redirect" class="redirect">
<input type="hidden" class="post" name="post" value="">
<input type="submit" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Button: (html)

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='button' var='DATAHERE'>sometexthere</a>
```

Javascript, or rather said jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('var');
    $('.post').attr("value",link);
    $('.redirect').submit();
});
```

this jQuery code listen's to any clicks on the items with the class `button` attached to them,
and reads out their "var" value, basicly you could use any kind of HTML element using this method as long as they have the `button` class attached to it.

Comment: Exactly fits my needs! Thanks!

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain the downvote? clearly the OP said this helped him solve the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing in HTML will cause a link to trigger a POST request or encode data in the request body.

You can [bind a JavaScript event handler to a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), cancel the default behaviour and then send a POST request by [programmatically submitting a form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) or using [XMLHttpRequest](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest.html). This generally isn't a good idea and you should use a submit button instead (which you can style to look like a link if you really, really want to).

Comment: Why did you ask the question then?

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser. So, no, you can't do it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. What you can do is set the value of an input type when the `<a>` tag gets clicked. Using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could get hold of the query string from the href attribute of the anchor tag (you would need to parse the href and get hold of the string on the right hand side of the & symbol) and then post it using javascript or jquery (easier to use jquery).

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Would have to ask why you would want/need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to open certain files according to $_POST values, doing this because of safety reasons regarding $_GET + url hiding.

Comment: The contents of your $_POST is very visible. Check your browser console and you can see everything that is being sent to the server. There isnt really any improved security by just using $_POST. Anything that is present in the browser is exposed

Comment: It's true that It is readable, but I'm more concerned of the input ;) + I don't like enourmous links with like 20 `$_GET values`

Comment: The $_GET is limited in length. It would be simpler to use a form and submit using as normal. Chromes console does show the $_POST - ALL developer consoles will or there is not much point in them. Do some reading on your options you are chasing a wild goose with this one there are better standard solutions than forcing none standard behaviours

Comment: Dude, take it easy xD I said I found it already, and No need to use Get anymore, I found a way using Azrael's awnser.

Comment: Ok good. Simply offering advice perfectly easy at my end. Carry on as you are