# $_POST won't fetch attribute set by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, x-editable

I have a HTML link element:

```
    <a href='#' class='editUsrProfile' data-type='text' data-pk='' data-url='file.php'></a>
```

I set the `data-pk` attribute with Jquery:

```
    $('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk', usr);
```

I check with console.log if `data-pk`has been set, and it's Ok.

But in my php script, where i check for `$_POST['pk']` i get nothing.
Other posts like name etc, that are static works just fine.

So, why can't `$_POST`read the attribute set by Jquery, and how can i solve this?

**UPDATE**
I use "Bootstrap Editable" to send data to php file.
The problem was i enabled `editable` before i had set `data-pk`. 
Simply i changed the events to first set the `data-pk`with Jquery.
And then i run the `editable`plugin:

```
$('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk', usr);
$('.editUsrProfile').editable({});
```

Comment: A link will not post you **anything**! Inform yourself about links, post and how to handle it in php. You did everything wrong here.

Comment: ok, i will edit my question. I also use Bootstrap editable.

Comment: I think you might want to read up on forms.. links do not send post requests

Comment: Hey, i use Editable to send the data. Why are you upset with something i did not ask?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629658/send-post-data-via-anchor-tag

Comment: Because you never stated your usage of editable in your original question

Comment: From where you are passing `$_POST['pk']`?

Comment: @NanaPartykar X-Editable are posting the data to the php file.

Comment: Did you do a simple `print_r($_POST);` in the php script to see what is in the $_POST array

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, also a var_dump. And all stuff like name etc that is static set will come. But not data-pk who is set by Jquery.

Comment: Did you check what is being sent from the browser, if anything

Comment: Did you check the browser debugger console log for javascript errors. One error even in some other js can stop other things from working

Comment: @RiggsFolly No erros.. i've checked the console.

Comment: Just for info.: Don't know how OP is using the code but he is using https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html in which `pk` is primary key and it is blank while posting to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `data-pk` is set on page load the you are initializing editable on page load too. But you are changing `data-pk` dynamically so you need to update your params of editable like,

```
$('.editUsrProfile').editable({
    params: function(params) {
        params.pk = usr;// or you can try $(this).attr('data-pk') or $('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk') whichever works for you
        return params;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank u Rohan, i will try this!

Comment: Perfect answer. I changed the run of editable to start AFTER i have set the `data-pk`. Now can editable read the attr, set by Jquery just before.

Comment: Glad it worked. But you should mention how you changed your `data-pk` dynamically and how you've initialized your `editable` in your question so that its easy to get and point out your actual problem for each SO user.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have $_POST values in php you need to use AJAX (you can use $.post jquery function): like this:

```
$('.editUsrProfile').click(function() {
   var self = $(this);
   $.post(self.data('url'), self.data(), function(response) {
      // do something with response from server.
   });
   return false;
});
```

not that this will also send url as $_POST value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pk = $('.editUsrProfile').attr('data-pk');

// URL : link file handle:
// example: localhost/getpost.php

 $.post(URL, {pd: pk }, function(result) {
        //Response from server
 });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please could you post a little explanation?