# how to use post method instead get for anchor tag

Tags: php

i already tried js function and php get method and this also

```
<a name='page' value='\"$next_page\"' href = \"$_PHP_SELF\">Next</a>
```

and accept as a variable but not working

i want to accept value by using post method through ANCHOR tag  instead get method. and i dont want to use any js function.
plz suggest any solution using post method only

Comment: The only way I think you could do this is by attaching the click event of the anchor tag to a JS function that makes a POST request.

Comment: You could try something like <a name='page' value='\"\"' href = \"$_PHP_SELF\\$next_page\">Next</a> or kinda like <a name='page' value='\"\"' href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page=$next_page\">Next</a>

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629658/send-post-data-via-anchor-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your best option is to use a form with a submit button that looks like a link.

It's impossible to use an anchor tag to send a post request. If using an anchor is a requirement then you need some javascript code.